# Magento 2.3 Add Multiple tabs after product description

Tags: magento2.3, tabs, product-page, product-description

I need to add custom multiple tabs after product description. Could you please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: please share the screenshot where you want to add Or have u trying to default magento theme luma?

Comment: Hi Amit thanks for quick reply, after product description in product details page i want to add two tabs in which one tab has Faq and other has videos based on custom code. I have two modules for that and i am using two catalog_product_view.xml layout file either of one file is working but two tabs along product description is not displaying.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like so:

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
<block class="Module class" name="unique name" as="alias if you want" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/attribute.phtml" group="detailed_info">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">class if you want to</argument>
        <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">none</argument>
        <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Tab title</argument>
        <argument name="sort_order" xsi:type="string">sort order numer</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
</referenceBlock>
```

Check the `Magento_Catalog::product/view/attribute.phtml` file to see the structure magento uses and do something close to this and change the above code as you needed, I would leave the title param so the tab title would get set as needed

Comment: Hi @Vlad, How to add more than one I mean two tabs at a time?

Comment: I would siggest duplicating the block, that is the correct way of doing it

Comment: I have two separate catalog_product_view.xml which has 1)Faq 2) Videos but only either one is displaying not two at a time.

Comment: so you have to catalog_product_view.xml in different modules? check if the block names are not the same, that might be the problem

Comment: block names are different

Comment: can you provide code samples?

Comment: <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
<block class="FME\Prodfaqs\Block\Product\Faqs" name="test.tab" template="FME_Prodfaqs::product_faqs_block.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
<arguments>
<argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Custom Tab</argument>
</arguments>
</block>
  <block class="FME\Productvideos\Block\Productvideos" name="productvideos.tab" template="FME_Productvideos::productvideos.phtml" group="detailed_info">
   <arguments>
    <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Videos Tab</argument>
   </arguments> </block></referenceBlock>

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="review_product_form_component"/>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
            <block class="Namespace1\Module1\Block\Class1" name="name.of.tab.1" as="tab1" template="Namespace1_Module1::file1.phtml" group="detailed_info">
                <arguments>
                    <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Tab Title 1</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <block class="Namespace2\Module2\Block\Class2" name="product.attributes" as="additional" template="Namespace2_Module2::file2.phtml" group="detailed_info">
                <arguments>
                    <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Tab Title 2</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Hi @Mohit, I have done the same as above your answer but no luck.

Comment: @gajjalasandeep, have you deployed static content after doing so?

Comment: Yes, I executed all commands but no luck !!!!

Comment: https://knowthemage.com/create-dynamic-custom-tabs-on-product-view-page/
This is the only best solution I have ever seen for adding a tab in product details page. It is working in 2.3.2.

Comment: @gajjalasandeep, great to know that you got your solution. It does not matter where you got it.

Comment: Yes and also thank you all for spending your valuable time for addressing my issue.

Answer (score 1):

[Create Dynamic Custom Tabs on Product View Page](https://knowthemage.com/create-dynamic-custom-tabs-on-product-view-page/)

This is the only best solution I have ever seen for adding a tab in product details page. It is working in 2.3.2.

Answer (score 1):

You can Use this Code in your `/app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml` layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product-guarantee" template="product/view/product-guarantee.phtml" group="detailed_info">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Guarantee</argument>
                <argument name="sort_order" xsi:type="string">15</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="customer-care" template="product/view/customer-care.phtml" group="detailed_info">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Customer Care</argument>
                <argument name="sort_order" xsi:type="string">20</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
</page>
```

It will look like this on Product Page -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In catalog_product_view add :

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.YourTabName" as="yourtabname"
               template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/attribute.phtml" group="detailed_info">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getYourTabName</argument>
                <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">YourTabName</argument>
                <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">YourTabName</argument>
                <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">none</argument>
                <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">YourTabName</argument>
                <argument name="sort_order" xsi:type="string">10</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block></referenceBlock>
```